# How to remove non-english words from the textual data in a csv file (python)

Tags: python, non-english

I am trying to remove non-English words from the textual data in a csv file. I am using Python to conduct this.

I read the csv file using this code:

```
blogdata = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/blogdatatest.csv", encoding = 'utf-16', sep = "\t")
print(blogdata)
```

At this point, there are 10179 rows left.

Then, I used the following code to remove the non-English words from the data, specifically in the 'posting' column:

```
blogdata = blogdata[~blogdata['posting'].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+')]
print(blogdata)
```

Then, I got only 3693 rows left. I think the code above removed the entire rows that have any non-English words.

I am struggling with how to remove those non-English words and save other parts, so that I can keep as many rows as possible.

I am sharing the dataset at the following website: https://github.com/GemmyMoon/nonenglish

Can anybody please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe you should run your function for every cell and this function could replace text (`blogdata['posting'].apply(your_function)`) .

Comment: As @furas suggested you will need to focus on the `posting` field of your data. You will need to split this into individual words, and then select only those words that pass your filter.

Comment: There is also [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: Thank you all. So you mean that I should tokenize the data first and filter the non-English words? I have tried the following codes as well: import nltk
nltk.download('words')
words=[word.lower() for word in words if word.isalpha()].  But it shows that 'word' is not defined. Is this code different from what you meant?